Long-term stability for a terrestrial planet with rings and a large sub-synchronous moon

Terrestrial earth-like planet with rings and moon (to scale, this was found in SpaceEngine and I love how it looks).

Rough Luna vs my moon apparent angular size comparison (Luna = 0.52°, my moon = ~4°)
The following list are parameters which I have to keep:
:

Mass of star: 0.78444 solar masses

Semi-major axis of planet from star: 0.53 AU

Mass of planet: 2.3797 earth masses

Radius of planet: 1.2478 earth radii

Rotational period of planet: 28 hours and 30 minutes

Inner ring edge from planet: 10,142km

Outer ring edge from planet: 17,980km

Mass of moon: 0.86111 lunar masses

Radius of moon: 0.22779 earth radii

Semi-major axis of moon from planet: 46,837.15km (5.8918 planetary radii)

Spin-orbital period of moon: 18 hours and 7 minutes (below geosync and prograde)

Moon inclination: 0°24’36.89” (to ecliptic)

Moon eccentricity: 0.000124

Moon-planet Roche limit: 21,375.875km


:
I am well-aware a moon of this size orbiting this close to the planet will have major tidal affects on the planet. It orbits the planet faster than the planet rotates. I am also aware that the rings of the planet will not last very long (billions of years). I just want them to last at least a few million years, or long enough for a good worldbuilding story.
My current explanation for the ring formation is that the rings of this planet formed from another, ancient minor moon, reaching below the Roche limit of the planet and collapsing into rock rings.
What other scenarios could explain the formation of the rings, taking into consideration the large, close moon to the planet, which might counteract significantly on the stability of the rings? (longer/long-enough lifetime is better)

What makes you think you can't have this setup? You appear to have already answered your question by saying, "I am also aware that the rings of the planet will not last very long (billions of years). I just want them to last at least a few million years...". Well... if they'll last billions then the answer to your question is yes, right? Keep in mind that per the [help/on-topic], we help people build imaginary worlds, so of course you can have this. Our focus is to help you rationalize a choice... that seems to already be the case here.

My concern is that the rings will collapse immediately due to the presence of the large sub-synchronous moon and its tidal effects. I know objects with rings can also have moons, but such a large moon orbiting below geosync orbit might be problematic in my case, that’s why I am asking if my rings are still possible to last in the time frame stated.

"Immediately" in astronomical terms is millions of years... at least. The biggest problem is the tidal effect the moon will have on the rings themselves (which I think is uber cool) that would, indeed, eventually (depending on size/distance of moon) cause the rings to either coalesce or to collapse - but that would cause some coolness before the planet restabilizes, too. But more to the point, this isn't [astronomy.se] or [physics.se]. The idea passes muster on worldbuilding - are you expecting to be judged by someone? There doesn't seem to be a worldbuilding question here.

The moon and planet I have presented don’t exist. They are worlds I am building. My idea is that the ring formed because a native minor moon got pushed (by the capture of the major moon) into its own Roche limit with the planet, collapsing it and forming a ring. The planet now has a ring and a large moon, which will also eventually orbit too close and collapse due to its sub-synchronicity. My question is, will gravitational interactions between the ring and major moon cause the ring to collapse within a few orbits or will it last for millions of years?

I get that... but I'm assuming (and that might be an error) that when you asked, "Can I have [this]?" what you meant was "can this exist in real life?" That's not really our focus. I like the idea and think it would contribute to a good story. So what's stopping you from using this idea and moving forward? That's why I don't see a worldbuilding question. It appears you're simply looking for scientific validation, and that's not worldbuilding.

I’m not asking if it could exist in real life, but rather, could it exist in our current understanding of astrophysics. I guess I should put a science-based tag on this question. I’ve had questions similar to this already answered before in worldbuilding so I don’t see how it could be better placed in any other stack exchange. If this question were transferred over to the physics or astronomy ones, they would probably close it for not being about a real life object. Keep in mind the planet I have built is also habitable.

I’m not asking if it could exist in real life, but rather, could it exist in our current understanding of astrophysics Those are the same thing. I'm back to my concern: what are you asking for? Scientific validation isn't worldbuilding. Can you have it? Yes. Will it last millions of years? Probably (it would take a cray supercomputer to prove it). We do not have a policy for review-my-idea questions and they violate Stack Exchange's current rule set. That previous questions were answered doesn't matter. What's stopping you from using the idea?

It would be helpful if you specify the things that are absolutely not changable (because essential to the story or so) and those aspects which you are willing to sacrifice or are okay when being altered to have alternative explanations. Idk, maybe the ancient moon is totally important to the story. Maybe the big moon can be replaced by something different. Is the gravitational system already fixated, or can the big moon be changed in weight (not in size) could also make things easier, etc. etc.

@Antares question amended.

Plausibility of the scenario & options
I have given the original idea more thought. I try to elaborate in the second part about the Roche limit. If you would like to have additional info, see this similar question about ring formation.
I'll break down the consequences for your scenario and show some alternatives:

Grinding the ancient moon to pieces will probably not work or requires very special circumstances. The moon has to stay on its Roche limit orbit for probably billions of years. Which seems to be impossible (see section about Roche limit).
More likely is that those rings formed as part of the planet, starting back in the early stages of the solar-system. At this point the "real" Roche limit applies, the rings form with highest probability below that limit).
This implies the rings do exist for probably billions of years and might also be considered stable for longer.
Life on the planet would be totally used to those rings existing from the beginning. Impacts from the rings might occur occasionally. More likely is an increased rate of shooting stars in the sky (might as well be non-noticeable, depending on particle size).
The advent of the big moon is the start for cataclysmic changes (given the need for the close orbit). Thus a plot needing both the moon and the rings, would have to deal with the advent of the big moon and the almost certain destruction of the ring formation within human-life timescale.
Most likely seems that the moon has a stronger gravity on the rings than the planet can counter, because of the close orbit and size/mass-ratio. The changes in the ring structure would be noticeable from very early on, I'd assume (within the first several revolves around the planet). More time can pass until the rings are fully dislodged, but at some point they also will start to impact onto the moon.
The big moon's influence on the rings is highly dependent on the circumstances of its approach. Namely: On which course and speed. On a  hyperbolical course the influence would be minimal, but the moon could not be captured. Needing the planet to be captured without destroying the rings,  would make it necessary to maintain a certain distance away to allow the gravitational forces to cancel out (at least for a decent amount to preserve the rings (long enough)). This would in turn change the apparent size of the moon. Quick solution: Make the big moon something hollow or very light compared to its size and try to find or make up an equilibrium orbit where apparent size and minimal influence on the rings match up.
In any case the big moon approaching the planet for the intention of forming another ring will be very violent in the end-phase. It will probably not be possible to disintegrate fully without crashing into the planet first, causing probably the extinction of all life. See next section on that topic.

Concerning the misconception of the Roche limit
The Roche limit describes a zone around a planet within it is not possible for gravity to coalesce matter enough to allow liquid or solid bodies to form. Thus, it is unlikely that a moon forms that close, rather than rings consisting of small particles instead. This assumes the formation phase of planets/moons in the early stages of the solar system.
It is not the other way around: It cannot be assume automatically, that any body of any size or mass crossing a special radius (the "real" Roche limit) disintegrates conveniently into tiny pieces in an instant!
If an object (moon or asteroid) is approaching a planet in a more or less straight line, which implies having a high velocity because of gravitational attraction, it crosses that limit in a very short period of time, thus there is almost no time where the "dissolving" can come into effect.
A very special case is a "Roche grinding"-effect (the term probably does not exist, but it conveys the idea, I think): This assumes a moon having an orbit around the planet that happens to be exactly on its "real" Roche limit or even below. The thought is: Given enough time and a stable orbit, the moon should disintegrate into tiny pieces forming rings.
While this is hypothetically imaginable, it implies a devastating scenario:

The moon has to be in a close orbit around the planet. For reference: The earth-moon-system has a "virtual" Roche limit of about 10,000km. To maintain that orbit, the moon has to have a very high velocity, revolving more than once a day probably (not computed it).

High velocity in low orbit cause high speed winds in the planet's atmosphere, increased tides/tsunamis to extreme levels, major gravitational influence on both the planet and the moon, both probably starting to stagger and rotate fast around a very close barycenter in between them (more likely even lying inside the planet's radius, meaning an increased force causing to destabilize the orbit, leading to inward spiral and impact). Rendering the planet's surface uninhabitable and causing major destruction on buildings, etc. also probably influencing day/night-lengths.

The moon appears very large in the sky, casting a big shadow revolving around the planet. For reference: Earth-moon distance is about 300,000km; assuming 10,000km as "real" Roche radius, the moon would appear about 30x larger.

Also to be considered is, that the Roche limit does not take the diameters of the participating bodies into account. Considering earth's radius of around 6000km and the moon's radius of around 1500km the effective distance of the surfaces is only about 2500km (assuming again a limit of 10,000km).

This means effectively: When a moon comes close to its Roche limit, this will not be able to form a sustainable orbit. It describes more like the end-phase of the moon spiraling down shortly before an inevitable impact with devastating consequences.


Distinction between "virtual" Roche limit and the "real" Roche limit:

The "virtual" Roche limit is what can be picked up from tables in books. This limit can be computed, but only because simplifying assumptions being made. The material composition and structural "integrity" of the moon is completely ignored. Only the average density is taken into account. Therefore it is only a "virtual" limit. It is an estimate (an upper bound) of the "real" limit.

Also distinguished are the "liquid" and the "solid" "virtual" Roche limits, referring to different kinds of densities used to compute them. The idea is that the "liquid limit" has to be larger than the "solid limit" thus allowing to also estimate a lower bound. The idea further is, that the "real" value is supposed to be somewhere in between (but that is not always the case!).

It is impossible to compute the real Roche limit for a body to obtain an exact radius at which it starts to dissolve (given enought time on that radius) or can only assume a "liquid" or "solid" form. This is due to the fact that the inner composition of objects is not known and can only be simplified by assumptions. But the inner structures greatly contribute to its stability, thus making it more difficult to break the coherence.

The "real" limit can turn out far different than the "virtual" estimated limit. It can turn out to be effectively non-existent, given a strong enough coherence of the body (The limit is lower than the planet's radius in this case).



I am well aware of the Roche-‘grinding’ affect you speak of. This is why for my ancient moon disintegration scenario I chose a minor moon (more like that of Mars’ Phobos) to be the moon disintegrating. Mars’ moon Phobos is currently in a sub-synchronised orbit around Mars and it will collapse and probably form a ring within a few million years. The capture of my planet’s major moon would help explain an orbital change allowing for the minor moon to go below the Roche limit quicker (and then grind up). This also keeps the planet from not being too devastated by such an event.

To be honest I am not too worried about changing my initial scenario for my ring formation, but what I am concerned with keeping is: the rings along with the sub synchronous major moon (with the parameters I have shown), the planet remaining habitable, and finally the rings not immediately being torn apart.

You do not need the major moon to "push" the smaller one below Roche limit. Actually, this would not help at all. To give the ancient moon enough time to disintegrate, it needs an (almost) stable orbit below the Roche limit. If a moon comes in and pushes it further down, the smaller moon gets into a downward spiral (an instable orbit) faster and will impact on the planet mostly intact. Going "faster" below the Roche limit does not increase the "disintegration rate" proportionally (on the contrary)! It increases the effect of the gravitational pull of the planet.

But what I get now is, the major moon is not supposed to be captured "at the end" of the system formation phase. It rather defines the start where the ring shall begin to form. And this is no problem for you if it takes billions of years from there -- A timeline might help to understand what-when-howlong-who is supposed to be able to live on the planet meanwhile and such. But actually, I think that might work! if you combine the "hollow" or "very light" moon idea, you can explain basically any orbit in close proximity and lowered influence of gravity.

A (recent!) comet-encounter caused the creation of the rings.
Plausibility issues
I agree with your assumption of the rings being prone do get ejected quickly because of the influence of the moon. But how quickly I cannot tell. I think, you can make that up as you want. In the second part below I give you some ideas to achieve a longer lifetime.
I show you a way to avoid the long phase were the small moon is grinded to pieces and the whole system is in turmoil, because of the big moon incoming.
Assume the planet already has captured its big moon for a while (long enough to find its equilibrium orbit; a little imperfect though, so the moon can spiral inwards over time (or as you like)). The ancient moon (small moon) is either also existing (but not crumbled or at least is okay to be swept away by the big moon) or you leave it out completely.
Then time the arrival of the comet (see below) in a way that it had enough time to crumble. Because the big moon is already there and stabilized, the rings can even appear in a more-or-less stable orbit around the planet as long as you like/need (maybe increase the amount of non-melting/non-vaporizing particles then).
Formation of the rings
Think of a (large) comet: Those mainly consists of ice and dirt, small particles munched together, ideal for being the basis for those rings.
That comet came into the solar system not too long ago, was caught by the gravity of the planet, was kept a time X in orbit. Because of the sun melting it down more and more (and the gravitational forces of the planet and moon) the comet became unstable, broke down into (larger, then smaller) pieces, emitting more and more particles. In the end phase, the debris was totally torn apart and the particles formed those rings, exactly as shown in the pictue.
The "cleaner" lanes inside the rings by the way, can be explained by larger pieces of debris (ice) that "sweeped" them clean (or almost clean), but are now melted away or also torn apart and dissolved into the particle lanes to the left and right. Also spreading from there into the cleaned lanes can add to the optical effects as needed.
If needed, you can add all sorts of materials and substances to the comet, which can cause interesting effects in lighting etc. Maybe it is not made of (water-)ice but methane. Maybe it contained particles of silver and those are sparkling in the sky, visible from the planet's surface. Maybe there are even dangerous particles in it (something alien, or radioactive) etc. etc. - imagination is unlimited here.
Prolonging the rings' lifetime
The following points are actually aimed at the crumbled ancient moon rings. But pick what you see fit, maybe the comet was not incoming that perfectly and you want other factors to explain things:
Actually, the picture shows the moon at a relatively high distance... But judging from the numbers, that should actually be just 50-100k something kilometers? My thought is: If you can increase the moon's orbit enough, so that the gravitational effects of the planet and moon cancel each other out exactly (or close to) the intended ring orbits, this might also be an argument for a prolonged lifetime of the rings.
You can also add some odd gravitational or magnetic-field characteristics to the planet which are beneficial to the lifetime of the rings. Or make the particles ionized and they act like kind of a increasingly active aurora borealis, when they close in on the planet. The magnetic field could also be a problem though, because it might repell the particles in the rings. In this case you might lower the magnetic field strength of the planet. Actually, this can also be beneficial to have some particles being repelled back into a semi-stable orbit. Needs to be balanced somehow... Magnetic field calculations vs. particle speed and gravity influence of planet and moon sounds like a hard problem to accurately compute, though.
Counter-acting the moon's gravitational influence could also be a high velocity of the particles which stabilizes their orbit (or is lower more plausible? So they need to be accelerated more first before being ejected). This might also account for a prolonged survival of the rings.
Also, those rings might not stay that perfectly circular all the time, but are pulled outwards more and more, causing them to spiral and smear (visually similar to the arms of the milky way) and the orbits become more elliptical before they totally dissolve. If you can live with some modified visuals, you can also justify a longer lifetime.
I am not too sure about this (maybe someone can help out here): Since the planet was captured, it could happen that this one revolves in opposite direction than the particles in the rings. Would this allow for an effect like a (partial) cancellation of forces?
The moon could also have special properties (especially when coming from a different solar system, the possibilites are multiplied), affecting things like magnetic field or material composition. Like for example: the thing is big, but not that heavy and the speeds are matching up so that the system stabilizes, because the moon does not exert a really high gravitational/tidal force and also the planet might have "just a little" lowered g because of less heavy materials in its core, meaning the ring particles do not get pulled in as quickly as one would expect.

My explanation for the ring formation was an ancient minor moon got driven below its Roche limit by the capture of the subsynchronous major moon; but I also like your comet explanation just as much!

Oh, the larger moon caused this? Okay. I thought there was some other event breaking the ancient moon and the big one was always there. I associated "ancient" with something spiritual actually. My bad! But cool you like the comet-idea :)

My idea is that a smaller native moon was already closely orbiting the planet before this major moon got captured, disrupting the orbit of the native moon to inwardly migrate below the Roche limit and then collapsing into a ring (explaining the crumbling without a huge impact). The new large native moon is also below geosync, and subsequently, it too will eventually go below its own Roche limit and collapse, perhaps even creating an even larger ring in its place. The large moon would create a lot more destruction to the planet though…

Not: "always there", I ment "already there"

Prioritize moon orbit vs. size vs. rings
I understand your intent, the goal is the optical effect of a large moon in the sky with the opportunity to have another ring some time in the future. But this fights with the rings around the planet on which the moon has a destructive influence (if it has) and every bit to counter that would help.
Maybe that are too many requirements to meet them all.
You could say the moon is not in an closing orbit. It is receding, albeit ever so slowly. The moon's size will also decrease, but fairly unnoticable over an extended period of time. In which the story takes place.
The benefit would be, the moon also pulling the rings away from the planet, countering (to some extent at least) the planet's pull.
The moon will also not break in the next X million years, unless you pull some cataclysmic event changing the orbit of the big moon at some point. (For example another moon incoming and hit the first one, both vaporize and the debris gets pulled towards the planet over time; or the sun going red-giant/supernova and breaking apart the moon).
The gain is a (more-or-less) stabilized visual effect of the rings plus a big moon. Maybe that is a trade-off to consider.
